# How to find out the number of a row DataGridView that matches the condition

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want the selected row highlighted in green

```
    private void FilterByRecordFilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WaybillGrid.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(FilterByRecordNumeric.Value)].
            DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

However, the id of the desired record from the database naturally does not match its number in the datagridview.
Is there any way to make the row number match id or is there some other way.

Comment: Is it windows forms application?

Comment: Yes, it's windows forms application?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. _”I want the selected row highlighted in green”_…? … If the row is “selected” then the UI controls “what” color the “selected row” IS and you can change this color from the grids `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` property. It is difficult to understand where the “ID” comes into play here. What is `FilterByRecordNumeric.Value` returning and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WaybillGrid.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
```